# Why doesn't this Glass app appear in the Glass Launcher?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

There is an Activity with data pulled from the remote API. The `Manifest` file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.glass"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The file`voice_trigger_start` works and the command from it is properly detected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trigger command="LISTEN_TO" />
```

The app does not crash, it works Ok, but it does not appear in the Glass Launcher. Look at the images.

[image]
[image]

All other apps I instal via the Market are here.

Why?

PS. I install my demo app via the console. It's not live app.

Comment: Could you share voice_trigger_start?

Comment: so, when you say "ok glass", there is no "listen to" menu?

Comment: The expected behavior is you'll see "listen to" menu and when you tap, you'll see your app under that menu.

Comment: @EntryLevelDev I checked and the app does appear and I can select it. But if I open the app called "Glass Launcher", I don't see my app there. Is this region maybe reserved only for published apps? As any app I install from the market, I can see there. But not mine installed via the console.

Comment: So you want to say "Glass Launcher" to trigger your app? sorry, I don't get your "Glass Launcher" part. It's not in standard menu

Comment: @EntryLevelDev Check new snapshots. Maybe I am using the wrong vocabulary. No, I don't want to say it. I want my app to appear there (if possible) when I instal it. Just like my demo app appears in the menu of Android phone.

Comment: Got you..."Glass Launcher" is a third party app. it's not a build in glass launcher so it's hard to guess what it really does. Anyway, please see my edited answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LISTEN_TO is one of the existing commands. The expected behavior is you'll see "listen to" menu and when you tap, you'll see your app under that menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trigger command="LISTEN_TO" />
```

If you want a custom command, try keyword.

voice_trigger_start.xml

```
<trigger keyword="@string/your_custom_command" />
```

**Edit**

Based on your comments, try adding this in your activity tag in your manifest.

```
<intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

You might need to reboot your Glass.

Comment: WOw! Launcher tag from regular Android apps. I will check this.

Comment: I guess Glass Launcher is ported from a normal android phone launcher. Hope it works the same way as a normal launcher.